# How to see if a user is following you on Twitter using C# Twitter API wrapper Tweetsharp

Tags: c#, api, twitter, tweetsharp

I see there is a API call for Frienships/Show, but I am not sure how to parse the response to get the true/false.

Here is my code so far:

```
    var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()
                    .AuthenticateAs(_userName, _password)
                    .Friendships().Verify(_userNameToCheck)
                    .AsJson();

    var response = twitter.Request();
```

Also, once authenticated, how to do set a user to follow you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TweetSharp you can access the friendships/exists API this way:

```
var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()
                .AuthenticateAs(_username, _password)
                .Friendships()
                .Verify(_username).IsFriendsWith(_userNameToCheck)
                .AsJson();
```

There is no way to "set a user to follow you", they have to choose to follow you on their own.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for that listed in the API Wiki. [The document can be found here.](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-friendships-exists) This will simply return true if it user A is following user B.
[Here is a list of Libraries](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Libraries) that probably support what your after.

Comment: Thanks!  I am new to .NET and trying to figure out the syntax for the TweetSharp library.